# Pillow image grab compute time independent of bounding box area

Tags: screenshot, python-imaging-library

I want to do screen grabs in boxes smaller than the entire screen. This is simple to do with:

from PIL import ImageGrab;
ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 1600, 1200)

I expected that when I halved the box area, I would see the time for the operation decrease by a factor of two. To my surprise, the compute time, just over 1/4 seconds on my new MacBook, was almost completely independent of box area.

Can anyone explain this to me? Is there any simple method to extract small rectangular regions from the screen very fast? The long compute time is very detrimental to my real time program.

Comment: Im not sure why this was down voted. Can I improve the description somehow? I am open to comments

Comment: @Mark, You are right in assigning this to overhead. But the results are very nearly independent of the box size. Can you recommend a reference that describes the buffering and explains the results - that would be an very welcome contribution

Comment: I am hoping for an answer that would provide example code to optimize the compute time. I don't have much confidence in my own ability to write faster code than is in the library, although I am sure it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Simply halving the image size is not going to result in much speedup, as the overhead of PIL function calls is what is taking up time. You may also have I/O constraints, depending on what you're doing with the images (i.e. saving them to disk) If you want speedups, you could look at multiprocessing libraries, or dropping down the image capture parts of your code to C with something like cython.